# Maven: using a dependency version as a property across different modules

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have got a project with a number of modules in it, now, e.g. I have a module M1 and its version 1.0.0 and in the same project I have got 8 other modules in which I have M1 as a dependency.

The problem is when I make a change in M1, update version to 1.0.1 and upload it to central repo, I have to change that version number 8 times.

I want to use this version number as property, which I have tried to put it as as a prop in parent pom but a maven warning saying its not right to do...

any thoughts? thanks in advance

Comment: please show us the relevant poms

Answer (score 0):

Don't define the version as a property.

Adjust the `<dependencyManagement>` section in the parent pom like below:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yourGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>M1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- eventually more dependencies -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In the 8 modules which depend on M1, insert:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yourGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>M1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Take a look at the [POM Reference - Dependency Management](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management) for further knowledge

Comment: thanks for comment, so <dependency> in the parent pom will come under <dependencyManagement> tag?

Comment: Thanks, so this way the version 1.0.1 will appear at two places 
1. in M1's pom and 
2. parent pom 
right?

Comment: No, if you go this way you have to define the version in the POM of M1 and in the Parent POM, but not in the modules which depend on M1

Comment: yeah thats what I said, in the M1's POM and in parent pom

Comment: but not in the 8 modules. Can you post your first trial which lead to your question, please?

Comment: sure will do that today/tomorrow, also need to try this above, this project is handed over to me and its horrible when it comes to how the project is structured.